# Evitar restar dinero al mismo tiempo al agregar sueldos en Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, reactjs

He estado buscando como solucionar este problema pero no encuentro como hacer esto.
Estoy trabajando con Firebase Realtime Database y React Js.

En mi aplicación tengo varios usuarios y cada usuario posee una cantidad de dinero. Tengo una tabla en donde cada usaurio le puede agregar un salario a un empleado pero antes de esto se comprueba si tiene el saldo suficiente para darale ese salario, es decir, si el usuario tiene $ 10,000.00 MXN al empleado no le puede dar por ejemplo $ 12,000.00 MXN.

Esto lo he conseguido con el siguiente código:

En el componentDidMount:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  var dbHelperRef = this.db.ref('business_1_Tables/' + localStorage.getItem('businessID') + '/money/' + localStorage.getItem('dateNow')).child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

  dbHelperRef.on('value', (snap) => {
    this.setState({
      globalMoney: snap.val().cantidad
    });
  });
}
```

y en el botón de guardar:

```js
var money = isNum(newData.sueldo);
var globalMoney = isNum(this.state.globalMoney);

if (typeof money === 'string') {
  alert(money);
  return;
} else {
  if (money <= globalMoney) {
    var save = this.dbRef.push();

    updateMoney('business_1_Tables', localStorage.getItem('businessID'), localStorage.getItem('dateNow'), money);

    save.set({
      empleado: newData.empleado,
      sueldo: money,
      usuario: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
    });
  } else {
    alert('No tiene el suficiente dinero para agregar un sueldo');
  }
}
```

Por si acaso esto significa this.dbRef:

```js
this.dbRef = firebase.database().ref('business_1_Tables/' + localStorage.getItem('businessID') + '/tables/' + localStorage.getItem('dateNow')).child('salario');
```

isNum es una función que tengo que comprueba si el valor es válido.

Y la función de updateMoney si es importante ya que en esta hago la resta:

```js
updateMoney(businessType, businessID, dateTimestep, amountLess) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
    var money = 0;

    var dbHelperRef = firebase.database().ref(businessType + '/' + businessID + '/money/' + dateTimestep).child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

    dbHelperRef.once('value', (snap) => {
        money = snap.val().cantidad;
        money = parseFloat(money) - parseFloat(amountLess);

        dbHelperRef.update({
            cantidad: money
        });    
    });
}
```

Y todo esto funciona bien pero el problema radica en lo siguiente, si el usuario ha iniciado sesión en dos dispositivos y agrega un sueldo al mismo tiempo el dinero del usuario quedara negativo inclusice esta el error de que si el usuario inició con $ 10,000.00 MXN y hace movimientos en dos dispositivos, el usuario podrá terminar con más de sus $ 10,000
00 MXN.

He leído que con las transacciones se puede evitar esto pero por lo que leo, solo sirve para incrementar valores de 1 en uno como por ejemplo likes y eso.

¿Alguien sabe como mantener esta consistencia de los datos?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final he optado por usar Firestore ya que tiene funciones mas avanzadas de transacciones y escrituras por lotes ya que Firebase tiene funciones de transacciones muy limitadas.

```
return this.db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
                            // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
                            return Promise.all([transaction.get(globalUserMoneyRef()), transaction.get(dbRef), transaction.get(dbDashboardRef())]).then((docGet) =>{

                                var sfDoc       = docGet[0];
                                var sfDb        = docGet[1];
                                var sfDashboard = docGet[2];

                                //alert(JSON.stringify(sfDb.data(), null, 4))
                                //alert(JSON.stringify(sfDoc.data(), null, 4))

                                if (!sfDoc.exists || !sfDb.exists || !sfDashboard.exists) {
                                    var message = "No existe la información.";
                                    this.refs.snack.handleClick("error", message);
                                    throw message;
                                }

                                var cantidadGlobal  = sfDoc.data().cantidad;
                                var oldCantidad     = parseFloat(sfDb.data().cantidad);
                                var caja            = parseFloat(sfDb.data().caja);
                                var caja_chica      = parseFloat(sfDashboard.data().caja_chica); 

                                newAmmount = parseFloat(newCantidad) - parseFloat(oldCantidad);

                                rest = parseFloat(cantidadGlobal) - parseFloat(newAmmount);
                                caja_chica += newAmmount;

                                if (rest < 0)
                                {
                                    var message = "No cuenta con la suficiente cantidad para modificar.";
                                    this.refs.snack.handleClick("error", message);
                                    throw message;                                    
                                }

                                if (caja > newCantidad)
                                {
                                    var message = "Existe dinero en caja por lo que la cantidad mínima que puede tener es: " + caja + ".";
                                    this.refs.snack.handleClick("error", message);
                                    throw message;  
                                }

                                var updateCantidadGlobal = transaction.update(globalUserMoneyRef(), { cantidad: rest });
                                var updateUser = transaction.update(dbRef, { cantidad: newCantidad });
                                var updateDashboard = transaction.update(dbDashboardRef(), { caja_chica: caja_chica });
                                var saveHistorial = saveHistory("Dinero negocio", newAmmount, "Se modificó la cantidad inicial de: " + oldCantidad + " a: " + newCantidad);

                                return Promise.all([updateCantidadGlobal, updateUser, saveHistorial, updateDashboard]);
                            });
                        }).then(() => {
                            this.refs.snack.handleClick("success", "Se ha realizado la operación correctamente.");
                            this.loadUserDash();
                            resolve();
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
                            resolve();
                        });
```

Como ejemplo escribo algo de código por si alguien lo necesita pero la documentacion de Firestore sobre las transacciones me parece bien solo que quisiera recalcar que si quieres hacer varios get en un return, es decir, leer varios documentos de diferentes colecciones, usen Promise.all y dentro especifican las rutas.